# Send Custom Post type fields to multiple emails

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

Actually what I am trying to do is that I want to send custom fields value to emails.

I have created a simple form in post type which only shows in front-end by this form user can enter there email and phone no. after submit the one mail goes to site owner, one mail is goes to business owner and one mail goes to email id of that particular user.

All the three mails have different content

Now Issues are

1. When I submit it the no. of mail received by each is equal to the no. of posts
   e.g I have 3 post item & when I click on one item and submit, it sends all the items details. I want to restrict it by one.
2. Site Owner and Business Owner gets the right info but the End user can't get the custom field value and custom fields are comes from advance custom fields plugin.

Is anybody there who can fix these problems.?

Thanks

Here is the code

```
    <div class="column one">
    <?php $pack= new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'packer'));?>

    <?php while($pack-> have_posts()): $pack->the_post();?>

<?php 

    $post = get_post( $post );
    $title = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
    $usermail=$_POST['email'];
    $cellno=$_POST['cellno'];
    $phone=the_field('phone');
    $pdesc=the_field('description');

    if(isset($usermail) && isset($cellno)){

        $to = 'siteowner@site.com';
        $subject = 'New Enqiry for'. $title;
        $body ="The enquiry for $title <br>Customer email is: $usermail<br> Customer Phone is: $cellno";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );


        $to = 'businessowner@business.co.in';
        $subject = 'New Customer Enquiry';
        $body ="The enquiry by $usermail <br>Cellno is: $cellno";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );


        $to = $usermail;
        $subject = 'Details For $title';
        $body ="Phone $phone <br>Desc is: $pdesc";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
         wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

    }
?>

     <div class="column one-fourth">
        <h1><?= the_title();?></h1>

        <?php $post_id= get_post()->ID;?>

        <img src="<?php the_field('logo');?>" />



        <a href="#desc-<?= $post_id;?>" class="fancybox">
            <input type="button" name="Details" value="DON'T PRESS THIS BUTTON"/>
        </a>
        <div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
            <div id="desc-<?= $post_id;?>">
                    <?php the_field('description');?>
                <?php the_field('phone');?>

                <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="cellno" id="cellno">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send" id="send">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>                      

    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()` to properly assign variables. `the_` echoes it.

That is:

```
$phone = get_field('phone');
$pdesc = get_field('description');
```

The issue with the emails is because you have the email sends in a loop.  That means that it's checking to see `if(isset($usermail) && isset($cellno)){` is set for each loop, aka the number of posts.

Fix this by passing in the post ID and confirming that.
Add the current post_id to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="postID" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
```

And check that it is equal to the current post ID in the loop.

```
 if(isset($usermail) && isset($cellno) && isset($_POST['postID']) && $_POST['postID'] == $post->ID){
```